# Search Bar doesn't work on Device in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I created iOS(5.0) application in that I have search Bar, which is used to search the content in server side, while passing keyword entered into search bar the list of content parsed from the xml and shown in Table View,

its working fine in Emulator,.but in device (ipad2 & iphone4s) its not showing table of content were searched.

pls let me know what am making wrong..

Thanks in advance,.

murali.

This is mySearchClass.h

```
@interface SearchClass : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIActionSheetDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>
{
AppDelegate *abc;
MBProgressHUD *HUD;

IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrv;
IBOutlet UITableView *tableV;
UISearchBar *searchBar;
IBOutlet UILabel *lblTitle;
IBOutlet UIActionSheet *actionSheet;
IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;
IBOutlet UIButton *btnActionSheet;
UIToolbar *pickerToolBar;

NSMutableArray *arrCate;
NSString *key;
}

-(void)cleartable;
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar;
@end
```

//======================

This is my SearchClass.m

```
@implementation SearchClass

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search"];

    UIImageView *navImg=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"i-street"]];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = navImg;
}
return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{ [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
     }

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage             imageNamed:@"bg1.png"]];
   abc = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
   //self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

   //[SearchClass initWithNibName:@"" bundle:nil];
   //[SearchClass initWithNibName:@"SearchClass" bundle:nil];

   arrCate = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Arts &    Entertainment",@"Restaurants",@"Bars, Pubs & Clubs",@"Film and Cinema",@"Live Gigs",@"Shops", nil];

   pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 43 , 320, 480)];
   pickerView.delegate = self;
   pickerView.dataSource = self;
   [pickerView  setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];

   pickerToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 56)];
   pickerToolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;   
   [pickerToolBar sizeToFit];

   NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
   [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

   UIButton *btnDone = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [btnDone setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)];
   [btnDone addTarget:self action:@selector(closeActionSheet)       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [btnDone setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"done.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   UIBarButtonItem *dbtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btnDone];

   [barItems addObject:dbtn];
   [pickerToolBar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
}
-(IBAction)closeActionSheet
{
    lblTitle.text=[arrCate objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
     return 1;
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row       forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
   return [arrCate objectAtIndex:row];
}
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:   (NSInteger)component
{
   return [arrCate count];
}
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:   (NSInteger)component
{

   lblTitle.text = [arrCate objectAtIndex:row];
   [abc.arrSearch removeAllObjects];
   [tableV reloadData];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section               {

//    NSLog(@"table view count seasrch :%d",[abc.arrSearch count]);
return [abc.arrSearch count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    NSString *imgUrl;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    else
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if(indexPath.row > 0)
    {
        UIImageView *separator = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"line1.png"]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview: separator];
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    UIImageView *imgbest=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(213,4,107,64)];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *actSpiner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    actSpiner.center = imgbest.center;
    [actSpiner startAnimating];

    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 2, 200, 20)];
    lbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18.0];
    lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lbl.numberOfLines=0;

    UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 23, 200, 20)];
    lbl1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    lbl1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"American Typewriter" size:13.0];
    lbl1.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lbl1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lbl1.numberOfLines=0;

    UILabel *lbl2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,44, 200, 20)];
    lbl2.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    lbl2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Oblique" size:12.0];
    lbl2.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lbl2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lbl2.numberOfLines=0;

    if([lblTitle.text isEqualToString:@"Arts & Entertainment"]) 
    {
        ArtsClass *arts=[[ArtsClass alloc]init];                     
        arts = [abc.arrSearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        imgUrl = arts.artThumpImg;
        lbl.text=arts.artTitle;
        lbl1.text=arts.artDesc;
        lbl2.text=arts.artDate;
    }
    else if([lblTitle.text isEqualToString:@"Restaurants"])
    {
        ResClass *res=[[ResClass alloc]init];                     
        res = [abc.arrSearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        imgUrl = res.resLogoImg;
        lbl.text=res.resName;
        lbl1.text=res.resType;
        lbl2.text=res.resPopularDish;
    }
    else if([lblTitle.text isEqualToString:@"Bars, Pubs & Clubs"]) 
    {

        BarClass *bar=[[BarClass alloc]init];                     
        bar = [abc.arrSearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        imgUrl = bar.barImg;
        lbl.text=bar.barTitle;
        lbl1.text=bar.barDesc;
        lbl2.text=bar.barFacilities;  
    }
    else if([lblTitle.text isEqualToString:@"Film and Cinema"])
    {
    FilmClass *film=[[FilmClass alloc]init];                     
    film = [abc.arrSearch   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    imgUrl = film.filmImg;
    lbl.text=film.filmName;
    lbl1.text=film.filmSynopsis;
    lbl2.text=film.filmReleDate;
}
else if([lblTitle.text isEqualToString:@"Live Gigs"])
{
    GigsClass *gigs=[[GigsClass alloc]init];                     
    gigs = [abc.arrSearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    imgUrl = gigs.eventThumpImg;
    lbl.text=gigs.eventTitle;
    lbl1.text=gigs.eventCate;
    lbl2.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",gigs.eventStartDate,gigs.eventEndDate];
}
else if([lblTitle.text isEqualToString:@"Shops"])
{

    ShopsClass *shops=[[ShopsClass alloc]init];                     
    shops = [abc.arrSearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    imgUrl = shops.shopThumpImg;
    lbl.text=shops.shopName;
    lbl1.text=shops.shopDesc;
    lbl2.text=shops.shopFacilities;
}
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imgUrl] ;                                    
//    NSLog(@"image link:%@",url);
dispatch_queue_t currQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0);
dispatch_async(currQueue,^{
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        imgbest.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    });
});

[cell addSubview:actSpiner];
[cell addSubview:imgbest];
[cell addSubview:lbl];
[cell addSubview:lbl1];
[cell addSubview:lbl2];

return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([lblTitle.text isEqualToString:@"Arts & Entertainment"]) 
    {
    abc.subClassTag=@"ARTS";
    abc.classTag = @"GALLERYCLASS";
    abc.strTitle = @"Arts & Entertainment";
    abc.objArt = [abc.arrArts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if([lblTitle.text isEqualToString:@"Restaurants"])
    {
    abc.subClassTag=@"RES";
    abc.classTag = @"GALLERYCLASS";
    abc.strTitle = @"Restaurants";
    abc.objRest = [abc.arrRes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else if([lblTitle.text isEqualToString:@"Bars, Pubs & Clubs"])
{
    abc.subClassTag=@"BAR";
    abc.classTag = @"GALLERYCLASS";
    abc.strTitle = @"Bars, Pubs & Clubs";
    abc.objBar = [abc.arrBars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else if([lblTitle.text isEqualToString:@"Film and Cinema"])
{
    abc.subClassTag=@"FILMS";
    abc.classTag = @"PLAYERCLASS";
    abc.strTitle = @"Film and Cinema";
    abc.objFilm = [abc.arrFilm objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else if([lblTitle.text isEqualToString:@"Live Gigs"])
{
    abc.subClassTag=@"GIGS";
    abc.classTag = @"GALLERYCLASS";
    abc.strTitle = @"Live Gigs";
    abc.objGig = [abc.arrGigs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else if([lblTitle.text isEqualToString:@"Shops"])
{
    abc.subClassTag=@"SHOPS";
    abc.classTag = @"GALLERYCLASS";
    abc.strTitle = @"Shops";
    abc.objShop = [abc.arrShops objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}


if([abc.classTag isEqualToString:@"PLAYERCLASS"])
{
    PlayerClass *pl = [[PlayerClass alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:pl animated:YES];
}
else if([abc.classTag isEqualToString:@"GALLERYCLASS"])
{
    GalaryClass *gc = [[GalaryClass alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:gc animated:YES];
}
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
scrv = nil;
tableV = nil;
searchBar = nil;
lblTitle = nil;
[super viewDidUnload];
}

-(IBAction)getCategory:(id)sender 
{
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];
actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                          delegate:self
                                 cancelButtonTitle:nil //@"Done"
                            destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];

[actionSheet setTag:0];
[actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view.superview];
[actionSheet addSubview:pickerToolBar];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view.superview];

[actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 430)];
}
-(void)cleartable
{
NSArray * ar=[tableV subviews];
for(int j=0;j<ar.count;j++)
{
    NSArray *arr=[[ar objectAtIndex:j]subviews];
    for(int i=0;i<arr.count;i++)
    {
        if([[arr objectAtIndex:i]isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {

            [[arr objectAtIndex:i]removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
}


-(void)showProgress
{
//[searchBar resignFirstResponder];

HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];

// Set the hud to display with a color
HUD.color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"box4"]];//[UIColor colorWithRed:0.23 green:0.50 blue:0.82 alpha:0.90];
//     HUD.opacity = 
HUD.delegate = self;


[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(download) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
}

-(void)download
{
if([NetworkManager checkForNetworkStatus])
{
   ParserClass *p =[[ParserClass alloc]init];
   NSLog(@"search bar text  %@ --- %@",key,lblTitle.text);

    if (lblTitle.text==@"Arts & Entertainment")
    {
        [p search:1 string:key];     
    }else if(lblTitle.text==@"Restaurants")
    {
        [p search:5 string:key];
    }else if(lblTitle.text==@"Bars, Pubs & Clubs")
    {
        [p search:4 string:key];
    }else if(lblTitle.text==@"Film and Cinema")
    {
        [p search:2 string:key];
    }else if(lblTitle.text==@"Live Gigs")
    {
        [p search:3 string:key];
    }else if(lblTitle.text==@"Shops")
    {
        [p search:6 string:key];
    }

    [tableV reloadData];

}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alrt = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Network Error!" message:@"Please Check your Network connetion.." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alrt show];
}
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 70;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar1 textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
if(![lblTitle.text isEqualToString:@"Select Category"])
{
    if(searchBar.text.length > 0)
    {
        key = searchText;
        [self showProgress];
//            ParserClass *p =[[ParserClass alloc]init];
//            NSLog(@"search bar text  %@ --- %@",searchText,lblTitle.text);

//            if (lblTitle.text==@"Arts & Entertainment")
//            {
//                [p search:1 string:searchText];     
//                }else if(lblTitle.text==@"Restaurants")
//            {
//                [p search:5 string:searchText];
//            }else if(lblTitle.text==@"Bars, Pubs & Clubs")
//            {
//                [p search:4 string:searchText];
//            }else if(lblTitle.text==@"Film and Cinema")
//            {
//                [p search:2 string:searchText];
//            }else if(lblTitle.text==@"Live Gigs")
//            {
//                [p search:3 string:searchText];
//            }else if(lblTitle.text==@"Shops")
//            {
//                [p search:6 string:searchText];
//            }
//            
//            [tableV reloadData];
    }
    else
    {
         UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Please Give me some Key words..!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
         [alert1 show];
    }
}         
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Please Select any Category..!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}

}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar1
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar1 
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

Thanks for ur Reply,.

Murali.

Comment: Please post some code.  We have no chance of diagnosing what's wrong without it.

Comment: Try check to sending request on network level.

Comment: Isn't it possible that your actual ipad / iphone device has access to internet, but can't connect to the host where the xml itself is on? 
Are you using a localhost address to test on?

Comment: NO,.Am using online server only, here it is my url for searching [search url](http://www.victoryvisions.org/iphonenewry/xml/xml-search.php?category=1&key=ring) the values for the query string values "category=" and "key=" are the user feeds based on the cate id parsing can be done. And both my ipad & iphone r connected via wifi,.

Answer (score 1):

wrong string comparison

```
if (lblTitle.text==@"Arts & Entertainment")
```

it should be like this - try this it must work & let me know.

```
if (lblTitle.text isEqualToString:@"Arts & Entertainment")
```

I am also having some issues in my search class, i am using JSON url.

Comment: Ok Ok .. You fixed right.. I am also having some doubts in JSON parsing. You give me some suggestion.

Comment: ya tel me whats ur prob,.??

Comment: Hi Murali, i had one doubt.                                                How to set a Proxy server in my machine so that i can connect to internet as a "US(America)" user.
I need to work with netflix.com and it won't allow users from India.                      And also it need to use inside VM-Ware because some proxy will not allow inside the VMWare.

Comment: here is my post                       (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162626/proxy-connection-settings-for-vm-ware)

Answer (score 0):

1. Where is the Parsing URL, what are the fields in the xml.
2. Check your parsing url in ur local browser by manual append method using query string ,working or not.
3. check by trace path, use console log for print the URL.
4. Check if u are using localhost url in ur program somewhere else.
5. Check your delegate for search class.

use this link for your reference.

https://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/50468-xml-table-view-searchbar.html

Comment: Pls take a look at the third command of my post there u can find the parsing url,.and I don't have any issue i my paring side coz the search is fine in simulator.

Comment: u are using some older version codes such as string comparison and object for key method mapping in ur program. this will not work in device such as iphone 5 or above or ios 6 .. Might be your device is ios5 above .. So that u should write a program in such a manner that it supports recent devices. Because apple is updating its product day by day. Use the latest MVC for xcode.